# Vuetify datatable horizontal scrollbar xs breakpoint

Tags: css, datatable, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vue and Vuetify on a Phoenix app. I have a datatable that has enough columns that it is too wide for small screen sizes. The datatable is nested inside a card. I want the card to be responsive and when the datatable is too big for the card, I want the datatable to have a horizontal scroll bar.

```
<v-container fluid grid-list-md>
  <v-flex xs12 sm8 md6>
    <v-card>

      <v-toolbar color="indigo" dark>
        <v-toolbar-title>People</v-toolbar-title>
      </v-toolbar>

      <v-data-table>
      </v-data-table>

    </v-card>
  </v-flex>
</v-container>
```

When it switches to the `sm8` or `md6` size, it displays the datatable with a scrollbar. How can I make it show a scroll bar on the `xs12` size when the datatable is wider than the viewport? I don't have enough reputation to embed screenshots, but two are linked below to show what I have and what I want.

[xs12, datatable overflows without scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq4KK.png)

[sm8, datatable overflows card, but has a scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D16r3.png)